# Excel Conditional Formatting with openpyxl in Python - Borders

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to add a conditional formatting rule to a workbook with the openpyxl module in Python.
I want to **format ONLY the right border of a cell**, if I do so, it removes all the other borders which I want to set to default, so that it doesn't overwrite borders which are already set/activated in the sheet.

Look at the following example which should only add a right border:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

border = Border(right=Side(color='FF000000', border_style="thick"))
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add('$A$1:$A$2', FormulaRule(formula=['A1="test"'], stopIfTrue=True, border=border))
```

---

**the code removes all the other borders...**

[image: result of code]

---

**this is my desired result which I cannot achieve with openpyxl:**

[image]

I couldn't find any Classes, variables or values which I could assign to the other parameters -> borders so that they wouldn't get erased.

I appreciate any tips.

Comment: How would you expect another result, if you assign only `right=...`? Read [standard-conditional-formats](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html?highlight=borders#standard-conditional-formats)

Comment: I do not want to format the other borders, I want them to be set to the "default" state as shown in the screenshot. The greyed out lines in the second picture respect other conditional formattings or already set borders per user input... there is no info in the docs how to assign the default state to the other borders.

Comment: There is nothing called "default state". Try to read the `cell.border` and update this instead of creating a new `Border`.

Comment: I take it that there are still no solutions to this?

Comment: hi jonfries. I couldn't solve the problem unfortnuately... 
I ended up formatting all the order borders with conditional formatting rules.
It did the job but it slowed the worbook a little bit down.